# Modify NSError localizedDescription

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nserror

Do you guys know if there is a nice way to set/modify a `NSError`'s localizedDescription after it has been instantiated other than recreating it? I didn't find any.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSError` declares no setters for its properties.  From this you can deduce that it probably is not meant to be modified after it has been created.  I could see writing a category on `NSError` that would create an error out of another error but with a different value for the `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` key.

Answer (score 22):

The [`NSError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSError/errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:) class is - like many Cocoa classes - immutable.

However, the doc states for `-localizedDescription` that:

> By default this method returns the object in the user info dictionary
>   for the key NSLocalizedDescriptionKey. If the user info dictionary
>   doesn’t contain a value for NSLocalizedDescriptionKey, a default
>   string is constructed from the domain and code.

So just use `errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:` to create a new instance or copy and supply an appropriate user info.

[Here's](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/handling-errors-in-ios-and-os-x-with-coc/240007940) another nice [introduction](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/handling-errors-in-ios-and-os-x-with-coc/240007940) to the NSError class.

Answer (score 9):

If you create your NSError manually specifying the `userInfo`, then you can rewrite this dictionary's value for key `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`. Just cast `error.userInfo` to NSMutableDictionary or whichever class you used when created NSError object